# CA Workload Automation AE Getting file name from file watcher in a dependent job which calls an SSIS package using the filename as a parameter

Tags: ssis, autosys

I currently have a file watcher set up in CA Workload Automation AE. This watcher copies a file to a file share. I need to create an command task that
starts when the file watcher completes (This is done) and executes and SSIS package passing the file name that was copied as one of the parameters.

My issue is that I cannot find a way to get the file name to pass.